# Python CRC32 continuous computation

Tags: python-3.x, crc32

understand that the simplest way to use build-in function for CRC32 computation is zlib. For example:

```
import zlib
zlib.crc32('hello-world')
```

However, what if i have a scenario which i want to read a 32 bit word (0x89abcdef) from a file and the file contain millions of 32 bits word?

if i read them line by line, and how do i keep the previous computation result and use it to continue the next line CRC32 computation until i get the final computation result?

Also, I'm not sure is the alternative way is it simply merge this few million lines to a single super long word and just feed it into the zlib crc32 function?

which one is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python's [zlib.crc32()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zlib.html) has an optional second argument which is the running CRC-32. You can compute the CRC of a series of chunks like this:

```
crc = zlib.crc32(chunk1, 0)
crc = zlib.crc32(chunk2, crc)
...
crc = zlib.crc32(chunkn, crc)
```

Now `crc` is the CRC-32 of the concatenation of `chunk1` through `chunkn`.